# Unable to make POST request to strapi v4.5.6 from nextjs frontend, getting 400 Bad Request status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, strapi

I am building an events app with nextJS and strapi. I am trying to make a POST request to strapi using nextJS on my local machine, to make a new entry to my `events` collection. However, I keep getting a 400 Bad Request status when making the request. I am making the request on my local machine from `http://localhost:3000` to the strapi server at `http://localhost:1337/api/events`. The request works successfully with postman.

Environment details:

- Environment: development
- Node Version: (node v16.16.0)
- Strapi Version: (strapi v4.5.6)

This is my code for handling the form submission to the strapi api:

```js
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/events", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data: {
            name: "test",
            description: "test",
            venue: "test",
            address: "test",
            performers: "test",
            time: "test",
            date: "2023-01-12",
        },
    }),
});
```

I made the permissions public and I'd also tried to solve this by configuring the strapi middleware for CORS which looks like this:

```js
module.exports = [
    // ...
    {
        name: "strapi::cors",
        config: {
            enabled: true,
            headers: "*",
            origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:1337"],
        },
    },
    // ...
];
```

Even after doing this I keep getting the same Response, 400 Bad Request with a message: `"Missing \"data\" payload in the request body"`. Am I missing something or is the body format incorrect?

This is my first time using strapi, and I found the above from the [strapi documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/middlewares.html#internal-middlewares-configuration-reference). How do I solve this issue, I have been stuck on this for a week now, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question, I had to create a slug system since my `events` collection had a slug field. I fixed this using a [lifecycle hook](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#declarative-and-programmatic-usage) to create the `slug` field with the use of the `slugify` library, which in turn solved this error(Validation Error).